# Shared preferences in flutter giving error on pub get

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, dart-pub

I started getting this error when adding shared preferences in a flutter app. It was working before and now I get

```
Because <app_name> depends on shared_preferences >=0.4.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub upgrade failed (1; Because <app_name> depends on shared_preferences >=0.4.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4 <2.0.0, version solving failed.)
    exit code 1
```

Here is the relevant part of my pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: "0.12.2"
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
```

I am new to flutter, and can't figure it out. I know that it was working before and it suddenly started giving this error.

Comment: It's not compatible with your current Flutter SDK version. Try to replace `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"` with `sdk: ">=0.1.4 <2.0.0"`

Comment: did that it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your flutter sdk is not updated. You would have to update it by running this command in terminal/cmd:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Here's a guide on how to upgrade your flutter sdk version: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you use an old package, which depends on `shared_preferences: ^ 0.4.0` and sdk version lower than 2.0.0. Neither *http* nor *progress_dialog* depends on *shared_preferences*. If you don't use other packages in your app, let me know, because it is weird. Otherwise (if you use more packages that you listed in the question) just use [dependency_overrides](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) to override dependencies

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: "0.12.2"
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12

dependency_overrides:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
```

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem, I changed the shared_preference to the latest version, as well as the path_provider obtained from the flutter pub site. that solved my issue

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30352187)